# Is it possible to provide conditional context in Handlebars.js?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a template

```
<div class="vehicle">
    <div class="model">{{model}}</div>
    <div class="price">{{price}}</div>
</div>
```

which is common for some context subparts (I can't change the context), let's call those subparts `car` and `bike`, and context has only one of those:

```
contractContext = {
    car?,
    bike?,
    ...
}
```

I need to make this template work regardless on which subpart is present. I can go:

```
{{#if car}}
<div class="vehicle">
    <div class="model">{{car.model}}</div>
    <div class="price">{{car.price}}</div>
</div>
{{else}}
<div class="vehicle">
    <div class="model">{{bike.model}}</div>
    <div class="price">{{bike.price}}</div>
</div>
{{/if}}
```

but my real-life templates are considerably bigger, so instead of duplicating those I'd like to use the context conditionally. I've tried:

```
{{#with car ? car : bike}}
<div class="vehicle">
    <div class="model">{{this.model}}</div>
    <div class="price">{{this.price}}</div>
</div>
{{/with}}
```

(and also `{{#with car || bike}}` which isn't enough for the real-life case because of more complicated checks), but `with` doesn't work this way ([sandbox](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/)). Is there some way to set context in a conditional way, or I have to handle this in JS instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is to implement some logic (vehicle selection) in a template. However handlebars and mustache are `logicless templates` that's why it's not superobvious thing to do in a template. I believe proper way of doing what you want is to have it handled in javascript (where all the logic should be).
Like :

```
const data = {
  vehicle: car || bike
}
```

And template

```
<div class="vehicle">
  <div class="model">{{vehicle.model}}</div>
  <div class="price">{{vehicle.price}}</div>
</div>
```

Also there's a hacky way of doing it using customHelper. Just to show how cool and customizeable handlebars are:

template:

```
{{#choseContext car bike}}
  <div>{{price}}</div>
  <div>{{model}}</div>
{{/choseContext}}
```

context:

```
{
  bike: {
    price: 422,
    model: 'foo'
  }
}
```

helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('choseContext', function(v1, v2, options) {
  let context = v1 || v2;
  return options.fn(context);
});
```

Comment: yeap, I'll probably go with using helpers, thanks for providing an example. Can you back your claim that handlebars is logicless by some link? I don't see that from the site really, and things like `{{#if}}` don't really look like logicless..

Comment: @YakovL, good point,  I've seen logicless part here: http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/, however it doesn't seem to be official sort. There's a mention of being logicless in old parts of source code (https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/components/composer.json#L3) But I guess this was changed so they don't claim handlebars to be logicless anymore

Comment: Well, I think this is the proper explanation: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1119#issuecomment-148753119